# Celery not running, no error message

Tags: python, windows, django-celery

We are using celery for some django task scheduling on a windows system.  It has been ticking along nicely for months without issue.  However today, after a restart (these happen almost daily) I am unable to get celery to run.  Celerybeat starts normally, however when I run Celeryd, it starts to load but then returns to the windows command line without throwing any errors.

Errors would make it significantly easier to diagnose, but without them I have no idea where to start.  I know almost nothing about Celery, the guy who set everything up has long since left the company, so I'm at a loss for what to do.

Any assistance in diagnosing the issue would be most welcome!  if there is any information that I will need to provide let me know.

**EDIT**

I located a log file which has the following:

```
[2011-10-19 14:32:22,924: WARNING/MainProcess] amqplib.client_0_8.exceptions
[2011-10-19 14:32:22,924: WARNING/MainProcess] .
[2011-10-19 14:32:22,924: WARNING/MainProcess] AMQPChannelException
[2011-10-19 14:32:22,924: WARNING/MainProcess] :
[2011-10-19 14:32:22,924: WARNING/MainProcess] (404, u"NOT_FOUND - no queue 'celery' in vhost '/'", (60, 20), 'Channel.basic_consume')
[2011-10-19 14:32:22,924: INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems RabbitMQ needed to be restarted.  I've learned much from this experience.